# AbstractTracker says Looper.prepare() is not called

Tags: java, android, android-looper

I don't use anything related to threads, but the emulator keeps saying:

```
12-15 14:19:22.807 20983-21204/edu.fontys.stayconnected E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

It there a way to debug some more, so to see why this error happens?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final OptionFragmentAdapter adapter = new OptionFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        if (viewPager != null) {
            SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tab_layout);

            slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                @Override
                public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
                }
            });
            slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        if (!NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this).contains(getPackageName())) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_notification_title))
                    .setMessage(R.string.dialog_notification_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_notification_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_notification_close_app, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

OptionFragmentAdapter:

```
public class OptionFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "OptionFragmentAdapter";

    private String[] titles = new String[] { "Lamps", "Apps", "Profile" };

    public OptionFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Current position: %d", position));

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new LampsFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new AppsFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "There is no fragment found for this position");
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

The slidingTabLayout is from google: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

Comment: Well, it claims it needs a looper thread (like the UI thread), and you are calilng it from a not-looper-thread (background thread).

Comment: There's an extra thread hiding somewhere in your app. I can't see it in the sample code you posted though. Are you using AsyncTask anywhere?

Comment: The 3 fragments only have a ```onCreateView``` method, there is nothing else..